# How to use list.where function with the objects getting casted before getting an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, list, linq, casting, where-clause

My classes are like this

```
public interface ICar
{
    CarModel GetCarModel();
}

public class Honda: ICar
{
    CarModel GetCarModel()
    {
        return CarModel.Honda;
    }
}
```

I have a list of `ICars` defined like this:

```
List<ICar> cars;
```

I am looking to extract a IEnumerable of all cars of type Honda using the Where clause and casted to Honda and not to ICar. 
How do I do this? Is this possible?

Comment: BTW more idiomatic C# would use a property not a method: `public CarModel CarModel => CarModel.Honda;` and it would need to be `public` to satisfy the interface.

Comment: Not, that type design like this leads to "double-typing". Noting prevents you from having `class MercedesBenz : ICar { CarModel GetCarModel() => CarModel.Honda }`. I'd recommend you to avoid it. The easiest you can do here is to throw away enumeration and use CLR type itself (@RichardSchneider's answer is the excellent example).

Comment: Why focus on using the `Where` method as it might exclude better code answers if strictly interpreted.. Just wondering..

Comment: Dennis, yes you are right. I could get rid of it, but may as well keep it to make logging easier if I change the enum to a property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = cars.OfType<Honda>();
```

See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: This is definitely the simplest option.

Comment: while your code is good, this is not really an answer, just a code dump. It should contain an explanation as well.

Comment: In terms of performance, since there is the enum `CarModel`, I am not sure this solution would be the best choice.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have nothing more to say,  Perhaps you can join in,

Comment: @Svek in terms of performance, the `OfType` only needs to iterate the `IEnumerable` once, while using `Where` and then `Select` needs one iteration over the entire `IEnumerable`, and another one over the results of the `Select`. so `OfType` is a winner here. However, this solution relies on the assumption that each car type has it's own class (which seems correct based on the sample code) but it's still an assumption, and it might be the best fit in this particular case but generally speaking, the `where...select` combination is a good fit for a broader range of selections.

Comment: @ananda shouldn't we allow other answers based on code the OP might not be thinking of?

Comment: @ananda, my real intent was to extract all objects of a certain derived type. Not necessarily to use the Where clause.

Comment: @ZoharPeled --- It seems like it is not as performant https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123407/3645638

Comment: @Svek interesting.

Comment: @RichardSchneider https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123407/3645638 here are the performance numbers

Answer (score 2):

`Where` only returns a filtered `IEnumerable`. You need to use `Select` also:

```
var listOfHonda = cars.Where(c => c.GetCarModel() == CarModel.Honda).Select(c => (Honda)c);
```

Comment: There's also the Cast method, `.Cast<Honda>()` would be equivalent to `.Select(c => (Honda)c)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, by something like this:

```
IEnumerable<ICar> results = cars.Where(s => s.GetCarModel == CarModel.Honda);
var hondas = results.Select(c => (Honda)c);
```

Comment: unless `Honda` can be implicitly converted to a string, this will not compile.

Comment: @ZoharPeled `Honda` is a class name in the context. Why in the world it should be converted to a string???

Comment: @ananda the fix is not really that great - now you are back to an `IEnumerable<ICar>` instead of an `IEnumerable<Honda>` as stated in the question...

Comment: @ZoharPeled I didn't had to convert to Honda, since I convert it in the second line.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missed the separation to two lines