# OfType(x) vs Where(_ => _ is x) vs Where with enum

Tags: c#

I'm a bit confused with the result here, maybe someone could give me some insights?

Basically, I am trying to test the performance between using

- `OfType(x)`
- `Where(_ = _ is x).Select((X)x)`
- `Where(_ = _.Type = type).Select((X)x)`

Here are the classes:

```
public enum AnimalTypes { Alligator, Bear, Cat, Dog, Elephant }

public interface IAnimal
{
    AnimalTypes Type { get; }
}

public class Bear : IAnimal
{
    public AnimalTypes Type => AnimalTypes.Bear;
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public AnimalTypes Type => AnimalTypes.Cat;
}
```

**edit: this code was fixed based on the comments! sorry for the error**
and here is the testing method

```
void Main()
{
    List<IAnimal> animals = new List<IAnimal>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        animals.Add(new Bear());
        animals.Add(new Cat());
    }


    // tests
    IEnumerable<Cat> test1 = animals.OfType<Cat>();
    IEnumerable<Cat> test2 = animals.Where(_ => _ is Cat).Select(_ => (Cat)_);
    IEnumerable<Cat> test3 = animals.Where(_ => _.Type == AnimalTypes.Cat).Select(_ => (Cat)_);

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    // OfType       
    sw.Start();
    test1.ToArray();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"OfType = {sw.ElapsedTicks} ticks");
    sw.Reset();

    // Where (is) + Select
    sw.Start();
    test2.ToArray();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Where (is) + Select = {sw.ElapsedTicks} ticks");
    sw.Reset();

    // Where (enum) + Select
    sw.Start();
    test3.ToArray();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Where (type) + Select = {sw.ElapsedTicks} ticks");
    sw.Reset();
}
```

Oddly, the results always ensure that the last test gets the best results...

Comment: Emh... you are only creating the queries, not actually executing them. Add a `.ToArray()` to the end of each query

Comment: And note that `type == type` is exact type comparison, while `is`/`OfType` support subclasses (for example a Siamese is a Cat, OfType<Cat>() and is Cat will both return Siamese cats)

Comment: This code is actually measuring jitting overhead, first one is always expensive.  Always repeat a test at least 10 times, you'll see this overhead disappear.  And get a feel for the numbers, 2 ticks is far too fast.  Otherwise easy to see by doubling the collection size.  Google "linq deferred execution" to learn more.  Once you fix it, beware the noisy results from very fast code like this, you ought to see that the Type comparison is fastest.  It should be, no need to check the type hierarchy like *is* and OfType needs to do.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I updated my code, but still getting unusual results.

Comment: Not sure about the down vote. Please let me know how to improve the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your testing code has three big problems:

1. You are not testing actual query execution time, you are only measuring the time taken to create the query.
2. The first test is unfair as you are adding the overhead of the loading of the assemblies.
3. You are running a single pass, which doesn't make a lot of sense when testing performance.

Look at something like this instead:

```
var animals = new List<IAnimal>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    animals.Add(new Bear());
    animals.Add(new Cat());
}

// remove overhead of the first query
int catsCount = animals.Where(x => x == x).Count();

var whereIsTicks = new List<long>();
var whereTypeTicks = new List<long>();
var ofTypeTicks = new List<long>();

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// a performance test with a single pass doesn't make a lot of sense
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    sw.Restart();

    // Where (is) + Select
    catsCount = animals.Where(_ => _ is Cat).Select(_ => (Cat)_).Count();
    whereIsTicks.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);

    // Where (enum) + Select
    sw.Restart();
    catsCount = animals.Where(_ => _.Type == AnimalTypes.Cat).Select(_ => (Cat)_).Count();
    whereTypeTicks.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);

    // OfType
    sw.Restart();
    catsCount = animals.OfType<Cat>().Count();
    ofTypeTicks.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
}

sw.Stop();

// get the average run time for each test in an easy-to-print format
var results = new List<Tuple<string, double>>
{
    Tuple.Create("Where (is) + Select", whereIsTicks.Average()),
    Tuple.Create("Where (type) + Select", whereTypeTicks.Average()),
    Tuple.Create("OfType", ofTypeTicks.Average()),
};

// print results orderer by time taken
foreach (var result in results.OrderBy(x => x.Item2))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{result.Item1} => {result.Item2}");
}
```

Running this multiple times, `Where (is)` can be a little faster or slower than `Where (type)`, however, `OfType` is always the slowest by a good margin:

1. `i < 10`:

   ```
   Where (type) + Select => 111428.9
   Where (is) + Select => 132695.8
   OfType => 158220.7
   ```
2. `i < 100`:

   ```
   Where (is) + Select => 110541.8
   Where (type) + Select => 119822.74
   OfType => 150087.22
   ```
3. `i < 1000`:

   ```
   Where (type) + Select => 113196.381
   Where (is) + Select => 115656.695
   OfType => 160461.465
   ```

The reason why `OfType` will always be slower is pretty obvious when you look at the source code [for the `OfType` method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d25cf953c577dcd6,references):

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> OfTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) 
{
    foreach (object obj in source) 
    {
        if (obj is TResult) 
        {
            yield return (TResult)obj;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the source items are type checked with `is` and then casted back to `TResult`. The difference would be bigger for value types due to the boxing.

Comment: Thank you. So the "winner" is Where (is). That was unexpected.

Comment: @Svek Not always, as I mentioned, sometimes Where (type) was faster. Do notice that there's a huge difference though in the results as the `Enum` wouldn't allow you to check for children while `is` would, as it was mentioned in a comment to the question

Comment: Ahh. Either way, I was expecting `OfType` to be more performant. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Svek You are welcome. See my update for an explanation

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto When you make tests, you don't want the GC to run... So you should try to minimize memory allocations if you can. Instead of `.ToArray();` (that will create two collections, one internally plus the array), use `.Count()`, that won't allocate anything.

Comment: @xanatos Hadn't thought of that (not really used to testing performance like this, to be honest), thanks! I will edit my answer with that suggestion

Comment: "As you can see, the source items are boxed" - no, there's no boxing here at all. The elements are references already. Boxing would only be involved if there were value types involved.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I knew I hadn't phrased that correctly, hope I clarified what I meant.

Comment: Yes, that's better.

Comment: To eliminate jitter/loading/warmup times, consider `whereIsTicks.Skip(1).Average()`